# How to use slider over an arbitrary list?

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, slider

I have a list that has no definitive pattern or incremental difference. Can I make a `Slider` go over the items in the list?

For instance, here is an arbitrary list of six elements, can a `Slider` go from `list[[1]]` to `list[[2]]`, etc.?

```
list = {0, 1, 2.22, 5, 141, 299};
```

Comment: Have you tried anything with a `Slider`? Take a look at `?Slider`, if I understand correctly it can handle what you need.

Comment: Sorry, I read the documentation (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider.html) and I found nothing that wasn't increment based. I'm sure I missed it.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a slider for an index to the list, from `1` to `Length[list]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by using both [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) and [`Slider`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider.html):

```
{Slider[Dynamic[x], {list}], Dynamic[x]}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Example**

```
Manipulate[
 i,
 {i, {0, 1, 2.22, 5, 141, 299}, Slider}
]
```

**Output**

[image: output]

**Reference**

[Manipulate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)