# make a slider for a list of matrices

Tags: manipulate, slider

I have a list of matrices, called $matList$, which are sequentially multiplied by another matrix $G$. I created a slider for $matList$, but the slider does not work. Here is the `Code`.

```
Clear[a, t, matList, G, solG, solGTr, mat];
Manipulate[
 SeedRandom[2];
 a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 5}];
 t = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 5}];
 matList = 
  Table[(# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]]) &[
    KroneckerProduct[a[[i]], t[[i]]]], {i, 1, 3}]; 
 G = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
 solG = G*mat;
 solGTr = Transpose[solG];
 Grid[{   
   {Text["matrix solG"], Text["transpose of solG"]}, {solG, solGTr}   
       }],
 Row[{Control[{mat, matList, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}]}]
 ]
```

The problem in the above `Code` lies in `Row[{control[{mat,matList,...}]`. A similar construct for a slider of a list of numbers works, though.

Comment: Replace `solG = G*mat`  with`solG = G*matList[[k]]`, and `Row[...]` with `{{k, 1}, 1, Length@matList, 1, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123152/how-to-use-slider-over-an-arbitrary-list

Comment: @kglr: Thank you very much for saving my day....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*More an extended comment than an answer.*

In addition to what kglr has said, you might have much more fun with this if you move the random matrix generation and the preliminary calculations out of the `Manipulate` environment:

```
Clear[a, t, matList, G, solG, solGTr, mat];
SeedRandom[2];
n = 30;
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 5}];
t = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 5}];
matList = 
  Table[(# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]]) &[KroneckerProduct[a[[i]], t[[i]]]], 
   {i, 1, n}];
G = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0,0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
Manipulate[
 solG = G*matList[[k]];
 solGTr = Transpose[solG];
 Grid[{{Text["matrix solG"], Text["transpose of solG"]}, {solG,solGTr}}], 
 {{k, 1}, 1, Length@matList, 1, Animator, AnimationRunning -> False}
 ]
```

Comment: it works perfect. You and kglr saved my day...

Comment: Always at your service. =)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe if you want a slider, use [`Slider`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slider.html):

```
SeedRandom[2];
a = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 5}];
t = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {3, 5}];
matList = 
  Table[(# - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[#]]) &[
    KroneckerProduct[a[[i]], t[[i]]]], {i, 1, 3}];
G = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 
    0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
Manipulate[
 With[{solG = G*mat}, {solGTr = Transpose[solG]},
  Grid[{{Text["matrix solG"], Text["transpose of solG"]},
    MatrixForm /@ {solG, solGTr}}]
  ],
 {mat, matList, Slider}]
```

---

If you don't have V10.4 or later or don't mind [nested `With`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with), you can use the following variant:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{solG = G*mat}, With[{solGTr = Transpose[solG]},
   Grid[{{Text["matrix solG"], Text["transpose of solG"]},
     MatrixForm /@ {solG, solGTr}}]
  ]],
 {mat, matList, Slider}]
```

The important thing about `With` in both variants is that ***it avoids an extra update*** by `Manipulate` that occurs if the global variables `solG` and `solGTr` are given new values as they are in the OP.  (When these updates are expensive, it can become a critical issue.  In the example demo, updating is fast and the waste of time doesn't matter that much.)

Comment: Your answer is yet another very good answer, formatting the output in MatrixForm for better visual effect.

Comment: I am having trouble in `Grid`, but I cannot figure it out where the cause of the trouble is.

Comment: @Tebernus What sort of trouble?  If you have an older version of *Mathematica*, it might be trouble with `With`: try `With[{solG = G*mat}, With[{solGTr = Transpose[solG]},
  Grid[{{Text["matrix solG"], Text["transpose of solG"]},
    MatrixForm /@ {solG, solGTr}}]
 ]]`

Comment: I have `Mathematica 10` and nested `With` works fine. Apparently, my problem was the old version of `Mathematica`. My question has been answered . Thank you very much.

Comment: I am back with one question for you. You mention `With` avoids extra update of the global variables. In the demo, $G$ and $matList$ etc. are outside of `Manipulate`. My question is: what if I have a nested `Manipulate` in which the current `global` variables are not `global` anymore. Is it then correct to say: new values of  $a$ and $t$ generated by  `SeedRandom[]` with a `Slider` $s$ will be taken **as given by the inner `Manipulate`** and hence simulations can be done using the slider for the inner  `Manipulate` only. I hope my question is understandable.

Comment: @Tebernus Whenever a "tracked" symbol is updated (with an assignment, such as `solG = G*mat`, whether it is global or local), *Mathematica* re-executes `Dynamic[]`-wrapped code. The body of a `Manipulate` is such a code. When you have nested `Dynamic` codes, such as a `Manipulate` within a `Manipulate`, things get complicated. There are many questions about it on this site, because it is hard to figure out. I can't give a general answer, but I might be able to respond to a specific code example. Generally, I avoid nesting a `Manipulate` inside another. There's usually a better way.

Comment: I have a specific example code but I cannot input it into this Comment Box. Is there any way I can post the example for you to see it?

Comment: @Tebernus You can ask another question with the code in it.